# Set Child Element Margin to Width of Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html like this

```
<fieldset>
  <label>Current Image:</label>
    <div id="logo_photo_div">
      <a href="#" id="link_image" target="_blank">
        <img src="">
      </a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In the actual example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/1/), the image has a `src` and what I want to do is, to set the margin of the `<img>` so that the margin stops where the width of the `<label>` stops.

I tried setting `margin-right:100%;` on the `<img>` but this extends it past the width of the label, so how could I set the margin of the `<img>` to stop at the right end of the label? And I don't want to just add on px to the margin of the `<img>`, I want it to change creative to the width of the label. So an ideal outcome can be seen [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/2/) **And I do not want to have the image fill the whole width.**

Thanks

Comment: How about `width:100%` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre because I don't want the image to be that large

Comment: But your question is about making the width of the child the same as the parent, that's what @RayonDabre's code will do...? http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/6/

Comment: Maybe you want to make `a` block http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/5/ ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that was a typo I wan to make the childs margin the width of partent

Comment: @Downvoters, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: *"an ideal outcome can be seen here"*. If you already have ideal solution, what the point of the question, I mean you already have what you are asking for.

Comment: @spenf10 Now used to this fieldset{display:inline-block;} demo http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/7/

Answer (score 0):

I edited your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kqgcLv9a/8/

the main change is in your jsfiddle

```
img {
    width:100px;
    margin-right: calc(100% - 100px)
}
```

enjoy

Comment: *"I don't want the image to be that large"*

Comment: I think he meant that by using width:100% it increases the height as well.

Comment: No I want the width to remain the same size as well

Comment: If you want the image to be in the full width of the parent, that's what I did. If you want it just to be in the middle then that's a diffrent question.

Comment: I don't not want it to be the full width and I don't want it in the center, I want it margin to extend to the width of the parent